# 'TypeError: undefined is not a function' when jumping 'tween modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, typeerror

I keep getting this issue in Node where my application crashes whenever I'm calling functions from one another.

I've made this minimum working example (working as in it gives me the error):

**Start module**

```
var module2 = require('./module2');

var data = 'data';

module2.doStuff(data);
```

**Module2**

```
var module3 = require('./module3');

function doStuff(data){
    // Stuff happens to 'data'
    module3.takeStuff(data);
}

function doSomethingElse(data){
    console.log(data);
}


module.exports = {
    doStuff: doStuff,
    doSomethingElse: doSomethingElse
};
```

**Module3**

```
var module2 = require('./module2');

function takeStuff(data){
    // Stuff happens to 'data'
    module2.doSomethingElse(data); // I get the type error here
}

module.exports = {
    takeStuff: takeStuff
};
```

The error I get is:

```
module2.doSomethingElse(data); // I get the type error here
        ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The `start module` calls a function in `module2` which ultimately calls for a function in `module3`, which in turn calls for a function in `module2`.

All modules are properly required and it finds the first method in `module2` just fine.

What's happening here and how would one go about this pattern when one needs to get a function from the module one came with?

**EDIT**

Debugging shows me that the module exists, but it's empty apart from the prototype it has. My question is why? Inside of Node/JavaScript, what's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a circular reference, module 2 depends on module 3 which depends on module 2 which depends on module 3 (and so on). So while trying to resolve `module 3` for `module 2`, it cannot complete it because `module 3` itself needs to be resolved first.

From https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles:

> When there are circular require() calls, a module might not have
>   finished executing when it is returned.
>
> In order to prevent an infinite loop, an unfinished copy of the a.js
>   exports object is returned to the b.js module.

So the module is available, but incomplete (which explains that you only receive a prototype). Circular references are a code smell anyway, try to avoid it :)

However, if you put both module 2 and 3 as a dependency in your starting module, it should work anyway.

```
var module2 = require('./module2');
var module3 = require('./module3');

var data = 'data';

module2.doStuff(data);
```

Comment: "When there are circular require() calls, a module might not have finished executing when it is returned." Well there you have it. *facepalms* And now there's an SO question mentioning it.

Comment: @JohnSnow Yeah, i will put that quote in my answer to clarify :)

Comment: @JohnSnow Would be nice if node threw a circular reference warning of some sort though. Glad to help!

Comment: Maybe a ticket to wish for?

Comment: The latest addition you mention withe the 3rd module in the start one doesn't work for me.

Comment: That is what I make out of the example on the node module documentation. I guess you need to use the notation @Targos mentions in his answer, to extend the exports object instead of overwriting it.

Answer (score 6):

This issue here can be easily fixed, while keeping the structure of your app (which is fine, in regard to circular references).

You just need need to keep the default `exports` object that is given to your modules by the system. Do not change it with `module.exports = {...}`.

The following should work:

#### Start module

```
var module2 = require('./module2');

var data = 'data';

module2.doStuff(data);
```

#### Module 2

```
var module3 = require('./module3');

exports.doStuff = function doStuff(data){
    // Stuff happens to 'data'
    module3.takeStuff(data);
};

exports.doSomethingElse = function doSomethingElse(data){
    console.log(data);
};
```

#### Module 3

```
var module2 = require('./module2');

exports.takeStuff = function takeStuff(data){
    // Stuff happens to 'data'
    module2.doSomethingElse(data); // I get the type error here
};
```

### Explanation

I'll try to explain what happens from the first line of your starting point:

1. In start.js, you require module2 and it is not loaded yet: the code from module2.js is executed
2. In module2.js, you require module3 and it is not loaded yet: the code from module3.js is executed
3. In module3.js, you require module2, and it is already loaded: the module2 variable now contains the exports object from module2.
4. The rest of module3 is executed and you change its exports object with `module.exports = {...}`
5. In module2.js, the module3 variable now contains the exports object from module3.
6. The rest of module2.js is executed and you change its exports object with `module.exports = {...}`
7. In start.js, the module2 variable now contains the exports object from module2.

The issue here is between points 3 and 6. Module3 is receiving the exports of module2 (3) before you change the reference to it (6).
Using `exports.method = ...` solves the problem because the exports object never changes.

Comment: What is the difference between exports.functionToExport and what I did?

Comment: @JohnSnow I updated my answer with a tentative of explanation

Comment: But when I debug, it enters into module2 and executes that code just fine, how could it do that is module2 is not loaded?

Comment: It is loaded, but it happens too late. When the code from module2 is executed, module3 already has a reference to its old (and empty) exports object.